# Autostarting a python GUI application on startup as local user (beagle bone black)

Tags: debian, gui, beagleboneblack, autostart

I am trying to start a GUI application (python3 project) on application startup. 
I've created a script in /etc/xdg/autostart/.

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
@xscreensaver -no-splash
export DISPLAY=:0
@/usr/bin/python3 ~/path/to/the/file.py
```

I've also tried the following script in /home/debian/.config/autostart/fileName

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
export DISPLAY=:0
@lxterminal -e /usr/bin/python3 ~/path/to/the/file.py
```

Something to note is that some of the libraries used are only available in "debian" login. Hence, I need to run this script as "debian".

Any suggestions on how to improve this? Currently, on startup nothing happens. I tried putting a touch command before the export command to see if the file is even invoked, I didnt see any file generated either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here : [Why does LXQT Autostart not do anything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449116/why-does-lxqt-autostart-not-do-anything?rq=1)

I updated the /home/debian/.config/autostart folder and created a new .desktop file with inputs:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=sh script_name
Path=/full/path/to/working/directory
Name=MyAppName
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```